# Why do I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when reading back a private class variable?

Tags: c++, class, runtime-error, exc-bad-access

I have a `Rectangle` class shown below:

Header:

```
class Rectangle: public Polygon {
private:
    float _width, _height;
public:
    Rectangle(float width, float height);
    float getWidth(float* width) const;
    float getHeight(float* height) const;
    bool isCollidingWith(Rectangle* other) const;
};
```

Selected Implementation:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(float width, float height) : Polygon(explodeRect(width, height, new struct vertex[4]), 4) {
    printf("creating rect %f x %f\n", width, height);
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
    printf("set _width to %f\n", _width);
}

float Rectangle::getWidth(float* width) const {
    printf("_w: %f\n", _width);
    *width = _width;
    return *width;
    //return (*width = _width);
}

float Rectangle::getHeight(float* height) const {
    return (*height = _height);
}
```

I initialize an instance of the `Rectangle` class, and the output indicates that the `_width` variable is being correctly assigned. However, when I later try to read the variable using the `getWidth` method, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on the line:

```
printf("_w: %f\n", _width);
```

Why can I no longer read this variable? I get the same problem with the `_height` variable as well.

EDIT: I would also like to note that if I skip reading the width, I get an error trying to read public variables directly from the object, e.g. when I try to read its x position with `obj->x`.

EDIT 2: Could this be from the fact that the object is an instance of a subclass of `Rectangle`, and this subclass is defined in a different file than `Rectangle` is? I am also reading the values from a third file.

EDIT 3: More code below.

I am trying to re-create Tetris with OpenGL. In my `display` method, I have this code to draw the rectangles:

```
if(fallingBlock != nullptr) {
    printf("drawing falling block at (%f, %f)\n", fallingBlock->x, fallingBlock->y);
    draw(fallingBlock);
}
```

`fallingBlock` is defined as a global variable at the top of my file:

```
Block* fallingBlock;
```

From my `main`, I call an `initVars` method that subsequently calls a `startDroppingBlock` method. Here it is:

```
void startDroppingBlock() {
    Block* block = availableBlocks[random() % numAvailableBlocks].copy();
    block->x = 0.5;
    block->y = SCREEN_TOP;
    block->dy = -0.01f;
    //printf("copied block is at (%f, %f)\n", block->x, block->y);
    fallingBlock = block;
}
```

And here is my block drawing method:

```
void draw(Block* obj) {
    bool shape[3][3];
    obj->getShape(shape);
    //printf("got shape: {%d, %d, %d}, {%d, %d, %d}, {%d, %d, %d}\n", shape[0][0], shape[0][1], shape[0][2], shape[1][0], shape[1][1], shape[1][2], shape[2][0], shape[2][1], shape[2][2]);
    /*float pieceWidth;
    obj->getWidth(&pieceWidth);
    pieceWidth /= 3.0f;*/
    float pieceWidth = obj->getWidth();
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            if(shape[i][j]) {
                Square rect = Square(pieceWidth);
                rect.x = obj->x + pieceWidth * j;
                rect.y = obj->y + pieceWidth * i;
                rect.color = obj->color;
                draw(&rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code calling `GetWidth`?

Comment: Why does your getter take a parameter and return a value? That's redundant...

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm trying to do a Tetris remake with OpenGL, so I have a `display` method that calls a `draw` method that draws the `Rectangle` using its width.

Comment: @Borgleader I was told that creating the variable inside of the getter method had the potential of causing a Segmentation Fault. I still have it return the value so I can use the method in-line.

Comment: @Greg returning a pointer or a reference to a local variable is a problem, but thats not what youre doing here.

Comment: Yes, but I want to see the CODE that calls `GetWidth` and `GetHeigh`, as I suspect you are not passing a valid pointer in, which would give you that result. But without seeing the code, the problem could of course be something else.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I have tried both `float pieceWidth; obj->getWidth(&pieceWidth);` and `obj->getWidth(new float)` - the actual error is on the line where I read `_width`, before I even use the passed in pointer.

Comment: Would it be too much to show ALL the code involved [I don't mean the whole program, but enough to get the context]. What you just showed looks OK, but without seeing it all in context, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: It's also possible, of course, that `obj` itself is "broken">

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of `obj` trought your program?

Comment: @MatsPetersson @Jeffrey `obj` is an instance of a subclass of `Rectangle`. Right before I attempt to read the width, I read a value using a method from this subclass that works fine.

Comment: Well, then I'm afraid you'll have to either break out the debugger and figure out what the problem is in your code, or post the code that is creating/using `obj`. Guessing what the problem MIGHT be isn't going to solve the problem.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I did post that code.

Comment: And the code calling that (where `obj` is created)?

Comment: `obj` is the parameter of the `draw` method, which is called by the `display` method. The global variable `fallingBlock` is passed in. `fallingBlock` is set in the `startDroppingBlock` method.

Answer (score 0):

> I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the line [...]. Why can I no longer read this variable? I get the same problem with the _height variable as well. [later...] I have tried both `float pieceWidth; obj->getWidth(&pieceWidth);` and `obj->getWidth(new float)` - the actual error is on the line where I read `_width`, before I even use the passed in pointer. [later...] I modified the getWidth and getHeight methods to just simply return _width and _height. Now I just get an error on return _width;

In this case I see you are using a `Rectangle*` pointer as `obj->getWidth` which can as well lead to a bad access error if `obj` is not a valid pointer.

---

It is to note that I don't quite understand your getter method at all. A simplified (and possibly *standard*) version of it might be:

```
float Rectangle::getWidth() const {
    return _width;
}
```

With the only difference that when you used:

```
// float a;
// float b;
a = rect.getWidth(&b);
```

you can now do:

```
// float a;
// float b;
a = b = rect.getWidth();
```

which is possibly cleaner and will surely don't cause such an error. A good rule of thumb is never to use pointers when possible. If you need to modify a variable inside a function just use a reference.

Comment: Alright, I modified the `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods to just simply return `_width` and `_height`. Now I just get an error on `return _width;`.

Comment: @Greg, it means your `obj` is not a valid pointer to `Rectangle*`. If you show me the code from where you declare `obj` to where you call `obj->getWidth` I'll probably find out where the problem rises.

Comment: @Greg, so `Rectangle` is `Block`? Where's the `Rectangle*` object?

Comment: `Block` inherits from `Square` which inherits from `Rectangle` which inherits from `Polygon`.